# How to do Terms Aggregation and nested sub Teams aggregation in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to achieve multiple nested level Terms aggregation over access logs. ( Terms Aggregation(user_id) --> Terms Aggregation(status) similar to Elastic Search)

Query tried

```
SELECT
    base_query_userid,
    base_query_userid_count,
    sub_term_aggr
FROM
(
    SELECT
        userid AS base_query_userid,
        count(userid) AS base_query_userid_count
    FROM esvsch AS base
    GROUP BY userid
    HAVING base_query_userid_count > 8
    ORDER BY userid DESC
    LIMIT 15
) AS base_query
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        userid AS sub_query_userid,
        groupArray(tupleArray) AS sub_term_aggr
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            (('status', status), ('count', status_count)) AS tupleArray,
            userid,
            count(status) AS status_count
        FROM esvsch
        GROUP BY
            userid,
            status
        HAVING status_count > 1
        ORDER BY status ASC
    )
    GROUP BY sub_query_userid
    LIMIT 15
) AS sub_query ON sub_query.sub_query_userid = base_query.base_query_userid
```

result

```
┌─base_query_userid─┬─base_query_userid_count─┬─sub_term_aggr─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│          83634308 │                       9 │ [(('status',200),('count',3)),(('status',400),('count',2)),(('status',500),('count',2))]                              │
│          73634208 │                       9 │ [(('status',200),('count',3)),(('status',301),('count',2)),(('status',404),('count',2))]                              │
│          63634108 │                      10 │ [(('status',200),('count',4)),(('status',301),('count',2)),(('status',404),('count',2))]                              │
└───────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Here we aggregate UserID and sub aggregate (over UserID aggregated subset data) status for each UserID field.

we plan to give dynamic field aggregation.

[Terms Aggregation means aggregate over subset data which is result of an aggregation.]

I afraid above query will become complex to form dynamically, and Nested Teams aggregation is needed like above

Is there any other ways in ClickHouse to achieve Multi level Teams Aggregation ?

Edit:
table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE esvsch
(
    `method` String,
    `uri` String,
    `session_id` String,
    `userid` Int32,
    `req_id` Int32,
    `_timestamp` DateTime64(3),
    `time_taken` Int32,
    `thread_id` Int32,
    `status` Int32,
    `ip` IPv4,
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY (req_id,_timestamp)
ORDER BY (req_id, _timestamp)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple nested level teams aggregation"? (ideally please include the table schema). Why does the query not scale? Did you measure runtimes?

Comment: @robert edited my response with asked details

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your desired response im not sure why you need a left JOIN. From what i can tell you just want the status counts for the top users.
I've simplified your table and column names for example purposes.

e.g.

```sql
CREATE TABLE test
(
    `user_id` String,
    `status` String
)
ENGINE = Memory


INSERT INTO test SELECT floor(randUniform(1, 10)) as user_id, ['200', '404', '502', '403'][toInt32(randBinomial(4, 0.1)) + 1] as status FROM numbers(100)



WITH top_users AS
    (
        SELECT user_id
        FROM test
        GROUP BY user_id
        HAVING count() > 10
    )
SELECT
    user_id,
    arrayFilter(c -> ((c.2) > 1), groupArray(counts)) AS statuses,
    arraySum(c -> (c.2), groupArray(counts)) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT
        user_id,
        (status, count()) AS counts
    FROM test
    WHERE user_id IN (top_users)
    GROUP BY
        user_id,
        status
    ORDER BY user_id ASC
)
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id ASC


┌─user_id─┬─statuses────────────────────────────────────┬─total─┐
│ 1       │ [('200',42),('502',3),('404',20)]           │    65 │
│ 2       │ [('403',2),('404',13),('502',5),('200',36)] │    56 │
│ 3       │ [('200',4),('502',2),('404',5)]             │    11 │
│ 4       │ [('200',10),('404',2)]                      │    12 │
│ 6       │ [('200',6),('404',6)]                       │    13 │
│ 7       │ [('404',3),('200',7)]                       │    11 │
│ 9       │ [('200',11),('404',4)]                      │    15 │
└─────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────┘

7 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.003 sec.
```

This should be very fast if you put the user_id in ordering key.

Comment: yes query is faster, i will adopt this techniques, my concern is how to do Terms Aggregration, is there any other ways ?. fyi,the Query i have shared is for understanding. but thanks for the response.

Comment: For the exact response you're after this is the best i know of. if you can make other compromises e.g. not inc. the total count across all status for a userid, obviously its a simple GROUP BY user_id, status with groupArray